# How to get profile image\phonenumber\country\address from Vkontakte and Facebook through OWIN GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, owin, facebook-oauth

my question is pretty similar to [Getting Basic Info from Google and Facebook through OWIN GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989701/getting-basic-info-from-google-and-facebook-through-owin-getexternallogininfoasy)

I have already setted up an external register, but can't take enough details from social profiles to fill account on my side.
Anyone know, how to get from facebook a mobilephone and homeaddress?
didn't find any claims here 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4

Comment: Facebook doesn’t provide users’ mobile numbers or home addresses via API.

Comment: @CBroe damn, thanks mate, how can I get profile image (800x800) then?